# Storing functors in a stl map and calling them

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to store `functors` in a `stl map` and then call it one by one , but now sure how to call it. This is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class BaseFunctor {
public:
  BaseFunctor() {
  }
  ~BaseFunctor() {
  }
};

template <typename T>
class MyFunctor : public BaseFunctor {
   public:
     T operator()(T x) { 
       return x * 2;
     }
};

int main ( int argc, char**argv ) {
  std::map<std::string, BaseFunctor*> m_functorMap;

  m_functorMap.insert(std::make_pair("int", new MyFunctor<int>()));
  m_functorMap.insert(std::make_pair("double", new MyFunctor<double>()));
  m_functorMap.insert(std::make_pair("float", new MyFunctor<float>()));
  m_functorMap.insert(std::make_pair("long", new MyFunctor<long>()));

  for ( std::map<std::string, BaseFunctor*>::iterator itr = m_functorMap.begin(); itr != m_functorMap.end(); ++itr ) {
    std::cout << *(itr->second)() << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

I cannot use `boost`

Comment: Is there a reason you say `functor` with Dr Evil quotes?

Comment: The operator precedence requires `(*itr->second)()`.

Comment: given that in your case each derived functor returns a different type, you'll have to deal with that, and that depends on what *exactly* you are trying to do with the returned values (and somehow I don't think `cout`ing them is what you are *really* trying to do)

Comment: @vladr: I have set of `write` function based on the type, I am currently have big `if` loop, which I am trying to avoid , I was thinking about `function pointers` but the types are different so cannot store them in a map and `boost` is not allowed.

Comment: Then consider a `Numeric` type that abstracts integer and floating point values, can be constructed from either POD, has a `write` method that will do the right thing and, for convenience, has `operator long()` and `operator double()` conversions to facilitate performing `Numeric` against `Numeric` computations. Then implement your functor in terms of `Numeric`. This `write` method, is it for serialization? Why not use the iostreams `operator <<` framework instead?

Comment: But before moving any further, what do your `write `methods look like, are they yours to rewrite (or have you no control over them?), and what lies on the other side of the gap you are trying to span? (i.e. where from do you get the `long`/`double`/etc. values you are trying to ultimately `write`? parsing them from a file? what does the file format and the code parsing it roughly look like?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a map full of `BaseFunctor*`, but `BaseFunctor` is not callable since it has no `operator()`. You cannot call without casting to a pointer of a derived type, preferably with `dynamic_cast`. Overall it doesn't look like a good design. You are attempting to use run-time polymorphism where it can't.

Comment: And when that is fixed, he would have a problem because `operator ()` binds tighter than `operator *`, so `*(itr->second)()` would first try to call and then dereference, but it should be the other way around.